# Problem with patindex() function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I created following table

```
create table publisher(
  name varchar(20), 
  city varchar(20)
)
```

I want to run following requirement:

> list all the positions of charcter 'a' from name.

For this, Ii ran following query:

```
select patindex('%a%', name)
  from publisher;
```

But, it doesn't show proper output. When i put 'city' column instead of 'name' column, it shows right output. What is the problem?

Also, I want to display the name of publishers whose getting minimum and maximum profit. for this, i ran following query:

```
select name, max(profit), min(profit) 
  from publisher;
```

It shows the error like that "'name' is not part of aggregate function". what should i do for retrieving name of publishers who getting minimum and maximum profit.

Comment: There's no limit to the number of questions you can ask -- these should be separate questions.

Comment: For the first question, what output does it give you?  Can you give sample data, expected outcome, and actual outcome?

Answer (score 1):

> list all the positions of charcter 'a'
>   from name.

To do that, you need a numbers or Tally table. You can simlulate it with a common-table expression if you are using SQL Server 2005 or later:

```
With Numbers As
    (
    Select 1 As Value
    Union All
    Select Value + 1
    From Numbers
    Where Value <= 100 --replace with max size of Publisher Name
    )
Select P.Name, N.Value
From Numbers As N
    Cross Join Publishers As P
Where Substring( P.Name, N.Value, 1 ) = 'a'
Option ( Maxrecursion 0);
```

> Also, I want to display the name of
>   publishers whose getting minimum and
>   maximum profit.

```
With ProfitRanks As
    (
    Select Name
        , Rank() Over ( Order By Profit Asc ) As LowestProfitRnk
        , Rank() Over ( Order By Profit Desc ) As HighestProfitRnk
    From Publisher
    )
Select Name, Profit
From ProfitRanks
Where LowestProfitRnk = 1
    Or HighestProfitRnk = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

The second question needs a group by:

select name, max(profit), min(profit) 
  from publisher
group by name

Comment: They want "The name of publishers whose (sic) getting minimum and maximum profit" NOT "The minimum and maximum profit for each group of publishers sharing the same name"!

Answer (score 0):

For part 2 of your question assuming an index on `profit` I'd use.

```
select name,
       profit
FROM   (SELECT TOP(1) with ties name,
                                profit
        FROM   publisher
        ORDER  BY profit) mx
UNION
select name,
       profit
FROM   (SELECT TOP(1) with ties name,
                                profit
        FROM   publisher
        ORDER  BY profit DESC) mn
```

This could be satisfied with 2 index seeks one at the start and one at the end of the index.

Comment: It's not working, SQL shows the error like that "check the syntax near '(' ". Please give another solution.

Comment: @Pooja - Are you on SQL Server 2000 or something? If so use `SELECT TOP 1` without the brackets. If not you must have messed up copying the example as the syntax is fine.

Answer (score 0):

RE: The issue with the PATINDEX function is because essentially saying you want to know the position of the first occurance of the letter 'a' in the value. That's how PATINDEX works (see [MSDN: PATINDEX (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx)).

If you want to get the position for each occurance, then you'll need to recursively search the string. Robyn Page & Phil Factor have some great articles on [string manipluation at www.Simple-Talk.com](http://www.simple-talk.com/author/robyn-page-and-phil-factor/)

The MAX and MIN functions are aggregate functions. When using aggregate functions, all columns must either be included in an aggregate or in a GROUP BY clause.

This should give you what you're looking for:

```
select name, max(profit), min(profit)
  from publisher
 group by name
```